# Have footer fixed when less content on clicks within page

Tags: jquery, css, fixed

How could I have footer fixed to always bottom when less content on all screens when on click content changed and have it fixed to bottom ONLY when content is less with CSS or Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try the following

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="wrap">
     MY Content
  </div>
 <footer class="footer" id="appfooter">
   <div>
    MY Footer
   </div>
 </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

css class(You can also add more properties according to the requirement)

```
 .footer {
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

In document ready

```
var footerheight = $('.footer').innerHeight();
var browserheight = $(window).height() - footerheight ; //footerheight
$("#wrap").css("min-height", browserheight);
```

Comment: Yes it's a nice update to get the Footer height dynamically

Comment: Yes and the best one @shu!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help for u.
by using `footer{ position: fixed;z-index: 100;bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;}` u can achieve fixed footer.

```css
footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100; 
    bottom: 0; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

</style>
<body>

<footer>
  <p>Posted by: Someone</p>
  <p>Contact information: <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">someone@example.com</a>.</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i need it ONLY when less content not always @Renuka CE